# Recover Kleopatra Notepad

Tags: gnupg, gpg4win, kleopatra

## TL;DR

Where does Kleopatra store it's notepad, if it does at all ? Where can I find information on the internal notepad feature ?

## Details

Is Kleopatra's notepad stored somewhere ? where ?

Kleopatra has an internal notepad. I was working inside it without exporting to a different file, when I took a break. When I returned, the computer have already restarted following a loss of power. The notepad looks empty now. I tried to recover it by looking for it in   `%APPDATA%\GnuPG` (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\gnupg) and in  `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG`, but I can not locate it there. Is there anyway to restore the file ? I looked all over in the most recent Kleopatra manual, but didn't find information on the notepad at all.

---

### System Info

- Windows 10 Home 22H2
- Kleopatra
  Version Gpg4win-4.1.0